# Can not select element using Selector result from Chrome

Tags: javascript, nodes, nodelist

I am trying to select an element with 'Selector name' and then delete it.

But I am unable to select the element :

Chrome give me Selector :

`body > zea-hub > div > div > zea-my-accounts > zea-section > section > div > div > div:nth-child(1)`

To select it I tried to use :

```
document.querySelector("body > zea-hub > div > div > zea-my-accounts > zea-section > section > div > div > div:nth-child(1)")
```

Which return `null`

and

```
document.querySelectorAll("body > zea-hub > div > div > zea-my-accounts > zea-section > section > div > div > div:nth-child(1)")
```

Which return `NodeList[]` I bet this is a good return

So I tried this way to delete this element :

```
var ChromeSelector = document.querySelectorAll("body > zea-hub > div > div > zea-my-accounts > zea-section > section > div > div > div:nth-child(1)");

ChromeSelector.parentNode.removeChild(ChromeSelector)
```

but it does not work... Am I missing something ?

```js
var ChromeSelector = document.querySelectorAll("body > section > div > div > div:nth-child(1)");
alert(ChromeSelector)
ChromeSelector.parentNode.removeChild(ChromeSelector)
```

```html
<section MySectionTest>
   <div _Firstdiv class="container">
     <div _Seconddiv class="Column">
       <div FirstSectionElement class="section">
         <h1 _ngcontent-kwd-c95="">Test</h1>
       </div>

       <div FirstSectionElement class="section">
         <h1 _ngcontent-kwd-c95="">Test2</h1>
       </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You need to read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). There's no way anybody can reproduce the problem from the scant information you've provided in the question.

Comment: Click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and post a [mcve]

Comment: You cannot remove a nodelist. You can remove each node - if you get a nodelist, check the length - if it is 0 then your selector is not correct

Comment: We have no idea until you post the relevant HTML

Comment: It is highly unlikely that querySelector returns null and querySelectorAll returns a nodelist with length > 0 - could this be a timing issue? Does it exist when you look for it?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return

Comment: @Dorian — Your code doesn't even try to do that

Comment: @Dorian — The duplicate explains. As did  mplungjan in a comment 15 minutes ago.

Comment: Try reading the accepted answer on the duplicate.

Comment: Useful to tell us what exact element you wanted to delete. For example by adding "Delete me" inside the div

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer was thank you [@Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin) :

```
var ChromeSelector = document.querySelectorAll("body > section > div > div > div:nth-child(1)");

ChromeSelector[0].remove();
```

Comment: Same as `document.querySelector("body > section > div > div > div:nth-child(1)").remove();`

Comment: That is impossible. If `document.querySelectorAll("body > section > div > div > div:nth-child(1)")[0];' works then so will `document.querySelector("body > section > div > div > div:nth-child(1)");`
`

Comment: Try to wrap it in `window.addEventListener("load”, function() { ... });`

Comment: Do you have access to the part of the script that inserts the divs you want to modify?

Comment: So that is where you add the script to delete